# Искажение данных при Ajax serialize формы - интересная особенность

Tags: ajax, serialize, php

Код формы:

```
<form action="/other/appointments" method="post" id="RecordToDoctor">
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="inline theme">
            <h2>Желаемая дата</h2> 
            <input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" maxlength="10" id="recordDoctorDate">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h2>Описание причины</h2> 
            <textarea name="reason" class="span12" rows="5" maxlength="150"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls ask_button"> <span class="help-block" id="dss"></span> 
        <input type="hidden" name="IdUser" value="217">
        <input type="submit" id="SendRecord" name="record" class="alllist" value="Записаться" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
</form>
```

Ajax метод:

```
function RecordToDoctor(el) {
     var datastring = $("#RecordToDoctor").serialize();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: {
             formData: datastring
         },
         url: '/other/Appointments',
         success: function (data) {
             $('#RecordToDoctor textarea').text('');
             $('#SendRecord').attr('disabled', true);
             $(el).closest('div').find('.help-block').text(data.message);
         }
     });
 }
```

Обработчик PHP:

```
public
function Appointments() {

    var_dump($_POST);
    die();
}
```

При выводе пришедшего $_POST - получаю:

```
array(1) { ["formData"]=> string(20) "date 05/29/2014&reas"}
```

Как видно, исказилось имя текстового поля: **reas** вместо **reason** и ко всему, значение не передано. Хотя поле заполнялось

Comment: Сейчас заменил serialize() на serializeArray(); - помогло...но в чем же прикол был?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk `console.log(datastring);` что покажет?

Comment: Показывает тоже обрубленные данные